# DropDown list not firing change event when it is altered

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a page with a dropdownlist and a button on it. The initial selection on the dropdown is an empty string. I do not want this submitted to the server so I disable the button. I then want to enable the button if any other selection is made on the dropdown. However my ddlBusinessUnit_SelectedIndexChanged method is never hit when I make changes in the dropdown list.

html:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlBusinessUnit" EnableViewState="true" runat="server" 
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlBusinessUnit_SelectedIndexChanged" />&nbsp;
```

code behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)            
        {
            dsDate.Date = DateTime.Today;
            PopulateBusinessUnits();
            StatusMessages.Visible = false;
        }


       bGetFiles.Enabled = false;
    }

 public void ddlBusinessUnit_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ddlBusinessUnit.SelectedItem.Text != "")
            bGetFiles.Enabled = true;

    }
```

Comment: set AutoPostBack="true"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `AutoPostBack="true"` for your dropdown.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlBusinessUnit" EnableViewState="true" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
 OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlBusinessUnit_SelectedIndexChanged" />
```

Answer (score 4):

you're missing `AutoPostBack="true"`  on your asp dropdown control

Comment: I think you got in just before me Sachin

Comment: don't worry Sachin-I got you